# How to create logical matrix in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, logic

Is it possible to create logical Matrices in Mathematica as it is possible in Matlab with `false(nrow,ncol)` or `true(nrow,ncol)`? And if so is it again possible to do for example `Xor[a,b]` with logical matrices `a` and `b` with same number of rows and columns?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes and yes. What's a and b? Boolean valued matrices?

Comment: thanks for the answer.any Matrices that return 0 and 1 and a and b are any arbitrary matricies with nrow and ncolumns lets say a[3,30] filled with 0 and 1

Comment: I don't remember if Xor is listable by default,(in which case it'll work as expected for your example), but you can use a=Table[0, 3, 30] to create a 3 row, 30 column matrix of 0s for example. Then, e.g. b=RandomInteger[1, {3,30}] and BitXor[a, b]

Comment: yes Xor was a matlab command  and thanks for the comment. one more question in matlab when you write a=false(nrow,ncol)  and type whos a you will receive logical class and in mathematica how is it possible to see data structure ? or it is not possible ?

Comment: See Maeder's wonderful book: https://goo.gl/DrC1hv

Comment: Mathematica is not a strongly typed language. The `b` that will result from my commands is, normally an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to `0` or `1` values, and *not* like in C, a pointer to the start of a sequence of integers. So in general there is *no* data structure. A moderately advanced topic, where this does become important, is when using `Compile` which requires tensor objects in its internal calculation, there you must keep track that arrays are rectangular, non-ragged and contain the same datatype in all elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example with random logical matrices an Xor-Operation:

```
m = 4;
n = 3;
a = RandomChoice[{True, False}, {m, n}]
b = RandomChoice[{True, False}, {m, n}]
c = MapThread[Xor, {a, b}, 2]
```

And this is a way to produce all-True and all-False matrices, repectively:

```
a = ConstantArray[True,{m,n}]
b = ConstantArray[False,{m,n}]
```

Note however that logical matrices in Mathematica are not packed as you can check with

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[a]
(* False *)
```

So their performance is limited when dealing with large matrices.
Thus, it may sometimes be better to use integer matrices and integer arithmetic. Compare these:

```
m = 4000;
n = 3000;
AbsoluteTiming[
  a = Developer`ToPackedArray[RandomChoice[{True, False}, {m, n}]];
  b = Developer`ToPackedArray[RandomChoice[{True, False}, {m, n}]];
  ][[1]]

Developer`PackedArrayQ[a]
ByteCount[a]

AbsoluteTiming[
  aXorb = MapThread[Xor, {a, b}, 2];
  ][[1]]

a1 = Developer`ToPackedArray[Boole[a]];
b1 = Developer`ToPackedArray[Boole[b]];
c1 = Developer`ToPackedArray[Boole[aXorb]];

Developer`PackedArrayQ[a1]
ByteCount[a1]

AbsoluteTiming[
  a1Xorb1 = 1 - Unitize[a1 + b1 - 1];
  ][[1]]

a1Xorb1 == c1
```

Edit:

And as [LLlAMnYP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26956/lllamnyp) put it in the comments, BitXor is blazingly fast:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  c2 = BitXor[a1, b1];
  ][[1]]
a1Xorb1 == c2
```